# Inserting a binary search tree in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I tried to create a binary search tree by using the insert function.
 
The the result was not what I expected, it only yielded the first
 
 
value of the node of the tree. Can anyone find out what is the problem?

 
Thank you!

And can someone check if my other functions are right too?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int val;
}treeNode;
int searchTree(treeNode *T, int key, treeNode *T1, treeNode** p)
{
    if(!T)
    {
        *p=T1;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(T->val==key)
    {
        *p=T;
        return 1;
    }
    else if(T->val<key)
    {
        searchTree(T->right,key,T,p);
    }
    else
    {
        searchTree(T->left,key,T,p);
    }
    return 1;
}
int insert(treeNode **T, int key)
{
    treeNode *p;
    treeNode *s;
    if(!searchTree(*T,key,NULL,&p))
    {
        s= malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        s->val=key;
        s->left=s->right=NULL;
        if(!p)      
       {
            *T=s;
        }
        else if(p->val<key)
        {
            p->right=s;
        }
        else
        {
            p->left=s;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
int delete(treeNode **T)
{
    treeNode *q;

    if(!(*T)->left)
    {
        q=*T;
        *T=(*T)->right;
        free(q);
    }
    else if(!(*T)->right)
    {
        q=*T;
        *T=(*T)->left;
        free(q);
    }
    else
    {
        treeNode *s;
        q=*T;
        s=(*T)->right;
        while(s->left)
        {
            q=s;
            s=s->left;
        }
        (*T)->val=s->val;
        if(q!=*T) q->left=s->right;
        else q->right=s->right;
        free(s);
    }
    return 1;
}
void preOrder(treeNode *T)
{
    if(!T)  return;
    preOrder(T->left);
    printf("%d\n",T->val);
    preOrder(T->right);
}
int main() {
    int a[10]={62,88,58,47,35,73,51,99,37,93};
    treeNode *T=NULL;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        insert(&T,a[i]);
    }
    preOrder(T);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is 62 rather than the whole array!

Comment: Your `searchTree` returns 0 if the tree is empty, otherwise it returns 1. So only only the first call to `insert` will insert a node and return 1, and the other calls to `insert` will return -1. Your `searchTree` should probably return the result from the recursive call to `searchTree`.

Comment: did you see the code examples on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search function does not work as you expect

You can just remove it and do :

```
int insert(treeNode ** t, int key)
{
  if (*t == NULL)
  {
    treeNode * s = malloc(sizeof(treeNode));

    s->val=key;
    s->left=s->right=NULL;
    *t = s;
  }
  else if ((*t)->val == key) /* I am not sure but it seems you do not want to insert several times the same key, else that case */
    return -1;
  else if((*t)->val < key)
    insert(&(*t)->right, key);
   else
     insert(&(*t)->left, key);

   return 1;
}
```

as you see the code is much more simple ... and it works

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall t.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
35
37
47
51
58
62
73
88
93
99
```

---

Your *delete* function doesn't work, if I add `delete(&t);` at the end of the main and I execute under *valgrind* there are memory leaks :

```
==14950==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==14950==    indirectly lost: 96 bytes in 8 blocks
```

A simple way to do is :

```
void delete(treeNode **t)
{
  if (*t != NULL) {
    delete(&(*t)->left);
    delete(&(*t)->right);
    free(*t);
    *t = NULL;
  }
}
```

After that change there is no memory leaks

Comment: Thank you so much! We meet again!!

Comment: @Liu yes, again ^^ Warning I supposed you do not want several times the same key, may be I was wrong, remove the associated code if needed

Comment: Your solution is better, but I still want to know what is the problem of my code.

Comment: @Liu your delete function doesn't work because you have memory leaks  and it is very complicated for nothing

Comment: @Liu step by step ^^ I let you fixing the _delete_ or I give you the solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190712/discussion-between-liu-and-bruno).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the return value from `searchTree`. When you do recursive calls you need to pick up the return value from those recursive calls. Like:

```
int searchTree(treeNode *T, int key, treeNode *T1, treeNode** p)
{
    if(!T)
    {
        *p=T1;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(T->val==key)
    {
        *p=T;
        return 1;
    }
    else if(T->val<key)
    {
        return searchTree(T->right,key,T,p);  //notice the return
    }
    else
    {
        return searchTree(T->left,key,T,p);  // notice the return
    }
    return 1;  // Not really needed...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: why do I need to pick up the return values from recursive calls??